# HDMI termination board

Tags: termination, hdmi

We are trying to make one HDMI termination board. This board will plug-in into my motherboard and emulate 1080p display. I want to use this termination board for EMC chamber testing of the motherboard device.

[image]

Can anyone help me if the circuit which I have drawn is good as terminating high speed TMDS + I2C?

Comment: What is a "brd"?

Comment: There are many things why this fails to be within HDMI and even DVI specs and why it fails to simulate a display. It draws too much current for starters. Even if it was within specs, it would not resemble a typical use case comparable to real-world case, where you have an actual cable going to an actual display. And still it would not support HDCP negotiation which may be a requirement for modern PCs to send any picture out.

Comment: Hi @hearth, Brd - PCB

Comment: Hi @Justme, Thanks for your message. I am thinking this PCB wil draw around 40mA which is still in the limit for HDMI. Yes it won't support HDCP but my host supports legacy hence should be able to read EDID from EEPROM. I am not sure why you said many things fails to be within HDMI specs. Can you please help me understand ?

Comment: @AtharvaUpadhye No it isn't within limits of normal operation, unless you assume that the simulated display is turned off. Please read the HDMI specification (which you should have if you have a license to manufacture and sell devices with HDMI) on how each of the wires should be handled to be within specification.